# How to call a function passed as argument in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Well this seems kind of basic and I've searched a lot for whats wrong with the code or how to properly do this. I'm trying to simply use a function, that is passed as an argument.

```java
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Anonymous {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

    public static void useFunction (Function<Integer, Boolean> fun) {
        boolean a = fun(10);
    }
}
```

It tells me that "The method fun(int) is undefined for the type Anonymous".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) is a functional interface with `apply` method, Since your function takes `Integer` as argument and returns `Boolean`, you have to call `apply` method by passing argument

> This is a functional interface whose functional method is apply(Object).

```
boolean a = fun.apply(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JavaDoc [`Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). You misinterpret the usage of the function with JavaScript - this is still Java. This interface has a method [`Function::apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-) which applies this function to the given argument.

```
public static void useFunction (Function<Integer, Boolean> fun) {
    boolean a = fun.apply(10);
}
```